# How do I get Windows 7 to recognize my second graphics card?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, device-manager, sli

Really hope someone can help--

I recently purchased a second EVGA Geforce 660 to run in SLI mode on my PC, but no matter what, I can't seem to get the PC to recognize it.

## My Specs:

- (2) EVGA GeForce 660 cards (the first one was previously installed and works fine
- Intel core i7
- 32 Gb ram
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit
- Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UD3H motherboard (latest Bios installed)
- 1000w power supply that is marketed as "SLI ready"

## What I have verified:

- SLI bridge is plugged in (does it matter which end connects to which card?)
- First card is in PCI-16 slot, per Gigabyte instructions
- Second card is in PCI-8 slot per Gigabyte instructions HOWEVER the GeForce 660 literature says that the second card should go in a second PCI-16 slot which I do not have available.
- Only one card shows up in device manager under "Display Adapters"
- The fan on the second card is working so it looks like it is getting power
- Card is seated snugly in the slot

## What I have tried

- I have updated the BIOS
- I have updated to the latest (not BETA) GeForce drivers.
- I have tried rebooting a bunch of times.
- I have tried banging my head against the wall and cussing out loud (didn't help)

Any thoughts?  Do I need to do something special in the BIOS?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it going past POST with 2 card plugged in? Have you tried switching the order of the card on the board? Have you tried switching the SLA bridge around? is pre-os boot is it recognizing the 2 cards(Brain fart for got proper terminology? What symptoms are being displayed that allow you to confirm the 2 aren't connected? eg. device manager only showing 1 card ect...

Comment: Have not tried switching the cards around but will do so in the next hour.  Will also try swapping the SLI cable around.  And, yes--in device manager only one card shows up.  Thanks.

Comment: I have now switched the cards around.  Now the new one is in the primary PCI slot and working but the old one isn't recognized--same as before